# Help With emails going to Gmail instead of Exchange

Tags: gmail

I am struggling to set up my Gmail correctly and would really appreciate some help with this.   I have an Exchange account and have recently setup a Gmail account with the same email address.

The problem is, all emails coming in are still going to Exchange and not coming through to Gmail.  Any ideas how to change this so the emails come through to Gmail?

Comment: You'll have to provide some more information. Is this a company email address? Have you edited the MX records for your domain?

Comment: Thanks for the reply - This is my companies email address which i setup as an Exchange account.  I have now set up the same email address with Google Apps for business.

Comment: The emails will only come through to my Exchange account, not the Google apps for business.   have looked at my control panel and i have no ability to edit the MX records as this option is not available.  Would Google apps for business work if i just deleted the Exchange account?

Comment: No, you will need to change the MX records. They are the only thing telling the outside world that email should be delivered to your Exchange mailbox. Another solution is to set up email forwarding from your Exchange account, to your Gmail account. For this, you will probably need to set up an alias domain that points to your Gmail account, and forward messages from Exchange to `yourusername@aliasdomain.com`.

Comment: Thanks for your help - i have contacted the company that has access to the MX records so hopefully they will get everything updated!

Answer (score 1):

The MX record is what is used to determine which server to deliver the mail message to. Without updating that, the mail will continue to be delivered to the Exchange server. You  could look into using the "Check mail from other accounts (using POP3)" option of GMAIL. Here is the [link](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=21289&ctx=mail&authuser=1) to the KB article on how to set it up.

Comment: Thanks for the response, unfortunately i am unable to get this to work as the email address on Exchange is the same as the one i have setup with Gmail